# Flash AS3: Using "string" to pass in E4X XML query

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript-3, e4x, xmllist

I want to be able to do something like

```
var XMLquery:String = "a1.a2.a3";
var parserVal:XML = parserMethod(XMLquery);
// or
var parserVal:XMLList = parserMethod(XMLquery);`
```

and get an output something like

```
<a3>Some value</a3>
```

**Important:** And I want to be able to replace the output at **a1.a2.a3** so using **descendants** is out of question. :(

So it's basically the ability to call xml query in string. Is there a way to do this. Just a hint would be super, I can do it if I got a bit of head-start.

Thank you!

---

I think I found a solution with the help from this link:

> [Updating an actionscript xml object directly in one line using e4x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3699183/updating-an-actionscript-xml-object-directly-in-one-line-using-e4x/3700289#3700289)

```
public static function updateXml(xml:XML, path:String, data:XMLList = null,update:Boolean = false,XmlListOnly:Boolean = false):* {
            var nodesArray:Array = path.split(".");
            var tempXML:XML = xml;
            var tempXMLCandidate:XML;
            var tagName:String;
            for (var i:int = 0; i < nodesArray.length; i++){
                tagName = nodesArray[i];
                if (i == nodesArray.length - 1){
                    if (data != null && update && !XmlListOnly){
                    tempXML[tagName] = data;
                    }else if (XmlListOnly){
                        return tempXML[tagName];
                    }else{
                    return tempXML[tagName].length();
                    }
                }else{
                    tempXMLCandidate = tempXML[tagName][0];
                    if (!tempXMLCandidate){
                        tempXML.appendChild(tempXMLCandidate);
                    }
                tempXML = tempXMLCandidate;
                }
            }
            return tempXML;
        }
```

You can call it like this:

```
updateXml(xmlHold, "words.exercise", sortedXmlList, true);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm too lazy to code and test it, but here's idea:

- Break your query on parts `"a1.a2.a3".split(".")`
- Go on the parts, calling `xml.elements(parts[i])` (you'll need extra (maybe nested) function for recursive calls)
- If you get non-empty XMLList, repeat calling `elements` on that list using next part.
- On last part, extract text from it with `children()[0]`.

Comment: Yeah! I did pretty much the same as you suggested. But twisted the code a bit to match my need. I've posted the code above, haven't got the time to check it properly.
Thank You for your help alxx! Really appreciate it.

Comment: If answer helps, don't hesitate to accept it... You get something for it :)